# Backpropagation Algorithm (neural networks)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I tried to implement an online backpropagation algorithm for a neural network.

After having computed every output and net value (ie the value without applying the activation function) of every node, stored in variables "outs" and "nets", I also try to compute delta values (induced fields at every node) and the variations of weights for every node; delta values are stored in a variable called "delta, whether variations are stored in a "delta_weights" variable, actually a three-dimensional matrix: the first index of this matrix is the level in which I'm working, the second represents a node in the network and the third is one of the connections entering in that node (synapsis).

In a first moment, this two variables contains all zeros.

Then I have written this code:

```
    for j in range(self.l):
    # self.l is the number of levels in the network: I'm running through all the levels
        if j == 0:
            # last level: output units
            for i in range(self.p[-1]):
                # self.p[j] is the number of units in level j: I'm considering every unit in the specific level fixed by the previous for cicle
                ei = np.subtract(target[i], outs[-1][i])
                # error of unit i in the last level
                deltai = ei * self.der_actfunct(nets[-1][i])
                delta[-1][i] = deltai
                for h in range(self.p[-2]):
                    delta_weights[-1][i][h] = eta * deltai * outs[-2][h]
        else:
            # other levels
            # going back until first level
            for i in range(self.p[-j-1]):
                temp = 0
                for k in range(self.p[-j]):
                    temp += delta[-j][k] * self.network[-j][k].weights[i]
                # calculating induced field of hidden nodes
                deltai = temp * self.der_actfunct(nets[-j-1][i])
                delta[-j-1][i] = deltai

                if j == self.l-1:
                    for h in range(self.n):
                        delta_weights[0][i][h] = eta * deltai * variable[h]
                else:
                    for h in range(self.p[-j-2]):
                        delta_weights[-j-1][i][h] = eta * deltai * outs[-j-2][h]

    # UPDATE WEIGHTS
    for j in range(self.l):
        for i in range(self.p[j]):
            self.network[j][i].set_weights(np.add(self.network[j][i].weights, delta_weights[j][i]), 0)
    return
```

My problem is that the training error actually increases after a little more than 10 epochs. I'm sure this is a mistake, so how is wrong with my code?

(I used an eta, the rate of learning, of 0.01)

Comment: Did you tried slower learning rate?

Comment: do you use iterations and optimization?

Comment: Slowing the learning rate only slows the process explained above, but training error still explodes.

Comment: I often find it useful to train the network with some simple test data (such as x,y coordinates to a straight line) before tackling my main problem. This should definitely converge to a global minima and will help to identify any bugs in my implementation.